# Honeycomb 3.0 programming guide, not XML, but Java UI

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Guys, I just want to know how to program in Java with Honeycomb 3.0 - I have taken several programming course, notably in Java, at IT.

I just want to get the basic on how to create layout, menus, pictures, activities, event listener, and etc. Purely in Java UI, not XML.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html.

Comment: You're going to have real problems if you don't want to use XML. Android is primarily a UI environment and XML files for layouts will save you a heap of time and effort when trying to cope with different devices. Just a thought. :)

Comment: Just an after-thought...you will be doing XML stuff as the manifest requires various components to be defined before you can even start an app.

Comment: Well.. there's an article about pro and cons of using XML or pure-do-it programmatically; I had to be sure..

Answer (score 3):

I would start with the documentation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html

fyi: UI programming can be done declaratively (XML) or at runtime (Java). Both ways are documented.